# C++ assigning to a object

Tags: c++, c++11

Why the last variable c do not print anything. **I know that is caused by destructors but i can't really find out why.** I thought that destructors only works when is called or is the end of function, program.

```
.....//
class Int{
private:
  int a;
public:
  Int(): a{0}{}
  Int(int s):a{s}{}

  Int(const Int& va) : a{va.a} { }  
  Int& operator=(const Int& r){ a= r.a;  }
  
  ~Int(){delete this;}
  int get() const{return a;}
 

};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Int& obj)
{
    os<<obj.get();
    return os;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Int& obj)
{
  .....//
}

  Int operator+(const Int& rhs,const Int& r) 
  {                           
    return Int(rhs.get()+r.get()); 
  }
   Int operator-(const Int& rhs,const Int& r) 
  {                           
   return Int(rhs.get()-r.get());
  }
   Int operator*(const Int& rhs,const Int& r) 
  {                           
   return Int(rhs.get()*r.get());
  }
   Int operator/(const Int& rhs,const Int& r) 
  {                           
   return Int(rhs.get()/r.get());
  }
 
int main(){
  Int a = 10;
  Int b = a;
  cout<<b;
  Int k = a+b;
  Int c= k*b;
  cout<<" "<<k<<" "<<c;
  c=300;
  cout<<" "<<c;
}
```

In advance thanks for explanation

Comment: `delete this;` is gonna melt your CPU.

Comment: **DO NOT** call `delete this`. Just don't. Especially not inside a destructor. Your destructor is being called because that object is already being deleted. Jumping the gun there results in a double free.

Comment: @tadman Potentially, infinite free.

Comment: @Evg I do love that modern C++ compilers are like "You want to delete yourself? It's your funeral." and let you do it anyway. Even clang which is normally pretty good about alerting you to potential problems is silent.

Comment: There are some rare legitimate use of `delete this`. In our code base, there is such code in the critical `release()` method, when the atomic retain count reaches 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your job in the destructor is to clean up any resources you've allocated or inherited ownership of as per the [RAII rules of C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii). It is **not** to delete yourself. That is not your job.

Since you have no allocated resources, your job is pretty simple:

```cpp
~Int(){}
```

Nothing to it, literally. In fact you can skip having a destructor completely. These are only necessary if you have:

- Pointers you need to `delete` or transfer ownership of
- Resources you need to release or transfer ownership of
- Inheriting from another class that ends up dictating the use of a destructor

Comment: but why does it trigger an infinite loop on c=300?

Comment: @Vladp Once you drive the bus off the road (undefined behaviour) anything can happen.

Comment: In OP's case it doesn't matter, but writing an empty destructor manually is a bad habit (most of the time), since it prevents move operations from being generated.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah, that's why I suggested ditching it unless it's necessary.

Comment: @Vladp When you assign `300` to `c` you create a temporary object of type `Int` first. It is destroyed right after assignment. But `delete this;` calls the destructor once again, hence you get infinite recursion.

Comment: @Evg pretty sure compiler optimizer it as r value. why else would you say `Int a=10;` works just fine? UB is pretty much the best explanation I guess, just so happen to print half way, could be both, could be none

Comment: @Vladp `Int a = 10` is not an assigment, it calls the `Int(int)` constructor, the same way as `Int a(10)` does.